# " had been about everything and done almost every where"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does this sentence mean in text below:
" there was a girl. She wandered all over the country hitching rides and shacking up until she'd been just about everything and done almost everywhere".

Comment: "Been just about everywhere and done almost everything" would make sense. It sounds as if the author is playing with words for comic effect, as in: "I'm going to wind the cat up and put the clock out."

Comment: For the first reference, consider *I've been a tinker, a tailor, a soldier, and a spy - in fact, I've been just about everything* (the subject has been / had the role of many different types of person). For the second reference, compare *I've travelled the world and seen many different cities. I've done Paris, New York, and London, for example.* In that context, to have "done" a place implies that place is some kind of "tourist attraction" that you've visited (so you can tick it off on your "list of places to visit).

Comment: defined comic effect. it's clumsy but as a native speaker I get the point.  Compare Bob Dylan's "but I was so much older then, I'm younger than that now".

Comment: and I'm going to syea

Comment: cripes, hit wrong button.  I'm going to steal this line is what I meant.

Comment: Interpretation of literature is off topic, unless there is a clearly identified source of concern which would be interesting to many future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inversion of the normal phrase **"done just about everything and been almost everywhere"**. This inversion is done for emphasis.

In a similar vein, one of my former colleagues used to say, "The early **worm** catches the bird."

The "normal" sequence will make a point but not catch anyone's attention. Bu the "inverted" sequence will raise eyebrows. When people get over their surprise, they'll remember the underlying point better (the one to which these phrases refer.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a reversal of the more typical phrase **"done just about everything and been almost everywhere"**.

She'd "been just about everything" because her experiences travelling caused her to take on different roles wherever she went (think changing careers, but less formal. One has "been a chef" and "been a programmer". She's "been everything").

She'd "done almost anywhere" is less clear to me, and might just be there because of the reversal of the phrase, or it could be an allusion to her "doing it", that is, having sex, anywhere (in bed, in a car, etc.). The fact that the text describes her "shacking up" implies that to me, as while the phrase just means moving in or living with someone, the implication is typically of a sexual relationship.

Comment: There is (or at least used to be) a usage of "I've done <place>" which means that the speaker has visited somewhere as a tourist and seen the main sights. For instance "I've done Paris" means "I've seen the Mona Lisa and the de Milo Venus, been up the Eiffel Tower, been driven round the Arc de Triomphe in a taxi, spent 5 minutes in Notra Dame cathedral and been on the Seine in a Bateau Mouche. I don't need to go to Paris again". I think that there is a element of that in this quote. In British English 'done' can mean 'conned' or 'ripped off' if it's used in the States that could apply as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's an inversion that is to be taken somewhat literally.  "Been just about everything" implies that she has had jobs, personalities or pretensions of every variety, while "done almost everywhere" implies she has had sex in many locations.